# Authentication error when setting the deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I am trying to set up the Authentication on Admin UI on Amplify, but I am messed up on the error it shows

[image]
I don't know where to set the deploy in order to add the login mechanisms.

Comment: did you add MFA as sms during deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset authentication

1 Sign in to the AWS Management console and open AWS Amplify.

2 In the navigation pane, choose an application.

3 On the application information page, choose the Open Admin UI tab.

4 On the Set up menu, choose Auth.

5 At the end of the Authentication page, choose Reset all authentication settings and users.

6 In the Delete authentication confirmation window, choose Delete all authentication rules.

7 The deployment progress displays in the upper right corner of the page.

8 After the delete authentication deployment completes, deploy new authentication rules

Documentations : https://docs.amplify.aws/console/auth/authentication#to-configure-how-users-log-in-to-an-app

Comment: Hi, I just tried to reset deployment, but it shows deployment failed, and the thing is I also tried to run amplify update auth and set up everything including Facebook and google login, and Ive also run amplify push and publish. However, it still shows auth error on my project